# Ex - silent mode won't read commands from a file when stdin is redirected

Tags: microsoft-windows, invocation, ex-command, silent-mode

I'm starting vim in Ex mode, silent mode, on Windows 10, in a standard command prompt window.  I'm trying to re-direct stdin from a file.  I'm using the terminal version of vim 8.2.2824.  It doesn't work, the commands from the file aren't executed.  When I kill it with CTRL-C, I get the errors shown.

```
C:\Users\paulc>vim -e -s <tempsource  
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? sleep 3  
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? sleep 2  
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? q  
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?  
  
C:\Users\paulc>
```

tempsource has the three lines:

```
sleep 3  
sleep 2  
q
```

I wait more than 10 seconds before killing it.  It doesn't help if the commands are prefixed with `:`  If someone knows how to get this to work I'd appreciate help.

Comment: I believe that is a different use of -s, which is equivalent to launching vim and running :source <filename>.  In that case -e isn't used.  When -s doesn't have an argument, it follows -e or -E, and it's silent mode.

Comment: That is, click the `?` and then 'code'.

Comment: Ok thanks I think I've got it formatted now

Comment: Looks like DBK formatted it. Do yourself a favor and read that help section that I mentioned. (You can also look at what DBK did.)

Comment: If there are still any outstanding formatting issues, please let me know.

Comment: No, it's all good. I'm just encouraging you to learn a bit of the syntax. Makes things easier for everyone. :)